# gradlew assembleDebug requires my release key password

Tags: gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, release

I added the signing settings as [the guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#configureSigning) says. Now when I run `./gradlew assembleDebug`, it requires my keystore and key passwords, and there are two APK files at the end:

1. ./Main/build/outputs/apk/Main-debug.apk
2. ./Main/build/outputs/apk/Main-debug-unaligned.apk

So Gradle builds a debug version of my module but requires the release key.

The build.gradle file of the built module is below.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword System.console().readLine("\nKeystore password: ")
            keyPassword System.console().readLine("Key password: ")
            keyAlias "my_key"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile project(':Log-Wrapper')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

**Update #1.**

The solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24281294/1065835 works, and I accepted the answer. But I personally prefer using the approach described [here](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/). Release keys are stored locally and safely, and there is no need to type passwords every time when compiling a release version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I could merge some suggestions picked up here and there.. ..and I got it working.

The problem seems to be the fact that writing ANYWHERE in build.gradle something like:

```
storePassword System.console().readLine("\nKeystore password: ")
```

it will be executed ANYTIME.

The solution I put together was, creating a signingCongif block BEFORE buildTypes block:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("c://my.keystore")
        storePassword "" // REQUIRED otherwise cannot be overwritten
        keyAlias "myAlias"
        keyPassword "" // REQUIRED otherwise cannot be overwritten
    }
}   

buildTypes {
    [...]
```

and tweaking gradle configuration with this:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
if(taskGraph.hasTask(assembleRelease) || taskGraph.hasTask(installRelease)) {
    // Only execute when we are trying to assemble a release build
    def passKeystore = System.console().readLine("\nKeystore password: ")
    def passKey = System.console().readLine("\nKey password: ")
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = passKeystore
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = passKey
}
```

}

Note that:
1. This block was outside and before the "android {}" one.
2. This was tested in COMMAND LINE execution only. Seems some fixes are needed where no console is available.

Comment: Not yet. And since it's not an answer, could you move it to the comments of my question, please?

Comment: This no longer works as of Gradle 4.6 I believe (or it seems to work when setting the value, but when actual signing is attempted, the keystore can't be read).

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though there are only 3 options:

1. Extract my signing config to a separate pseduo-project
2. Automate the signature, but sign EVERYTHING with release keys
3. Enter the passwords manually on the command line

This is my workaround and your 4th option to achieve a perfect balance:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if(taskGraph.hasTask(':app:assembleRelease')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(KEYSTORE)
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = STOREPASS
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = KEY_ALIAS
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = KEYPASS
    }
}

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {

        }
        release {

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
    debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            ...
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to use a stored key and signature ONLY on release builds